# Debugging selenium webdriver and can view elements as expected in debugger, but when queried in my script they show up empty

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pycharm

I am trying to automate some web scraping and threw together a python script using selenium webdriver. I implemented implicit and explicit waits successfully earlier in the script.

While debugging in PyCharm, I can see the all attributes/values of each thumbnail (WebElement) object as expected, including the text. But then the text field is empty MOST of the time when I attempt to access it in the script. I have tried all sorts of waiting conditions in the EC class.

```
    try:
        # wait 30 seconds before looking for element
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'thumbnail'))
        )
    except:
        # else quit
        driver.quit()
        quit(1)

thumbnails = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('thumbnail')
for thumbnail in thumbnails:
    try:
        # wait 30 seconds before looking for element
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(len(thumbnail.text) != 0)
    except:
        # else quit
        driver.quit()
        quit(1)
    time = thumbnail.text
    h, m = time.strip().split(':')
    url = thumbnail.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'slides/' + h + '_' + m + '.jpg')
```

Seeing as occasionally I do get expected behavior in the script, I have to assume there's some weird race condition going on here each time I query anything. I'm just clueless as to what that could be. My next thought is to grab the HTML as a string via driver.pagesource and use LXML to parse it, but obviously that's a workaround.

Why can I always see the values in my debugger and how could this behavior be possible? Also, in the final try/except, the except clause executes well before 30 seconds...

Edit: I've attached relevant HTML

```
<!-- Thumbnail template -->
                    <script id="thumbnailTemplate" type="text/template">
                        <@ _.each(thumbnails, function (thumbnail) { @>
                            <li id="<@= thumbnail.id @>"
                                class="thumbnail"
                                tabindex="0"
                                role="button"
                                aria-label="<@= Panopto.GlobalResources.Viewer_Aria_JumpToTimestamp.format(thumbnail.timestamp)@>"
                                style="display:none;">
                                <div class="thumbnail-highlight accent-background safety-accent-border"
                                    aria-label="Jump to {0}"></div>
                                <img data-src="<@= thumbnail.src @>" aria-hidden="true" />
                                <div class="thumbnail-timestamp"
                                    aria-label="<@= thumbnail.text ? thumbnail.text : Panopto.GlobalResources.Viewer_Aria_HideThumbnailTimeFormat.format(thumbnail.timestamp)@>"
                                    ><@= thumbnail.timestamp @></div>
                                <@ if (thumbnail.editable) { @>
                                    <div class="thumbnail-buttons" style="display:none;">
                                        <i class="thumbnail-edit material-icons" tabindex="0" title="Edit">&#xE150;</i><!-- whitespace
                                     --><i class="thumbnail-delete material-icons" tabindex="0" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i>
                                    </div>
                                <@ } @>
                            </li>
                        <@ }); @>
                    </script>

                    <ol id="thumbnailList" class="thumbnail-strip" aria-label="Preview image list" style="width: 480px;">
                        
                            <li id="thumbnail9thumbnailList" class="thumbnail highlighted" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Jump to 0:00" style="display: none;" aria-current="true">
                                <div class="thumbnail-highlight accent-background safety-accent-border" aria-label="Jump to {0}"></div>
                                <img data-src="https://pitt.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Viewer/Thumb.aspx?eventTargetPID=db184992-2dd3-4257-aa24-ac10003dcc84&amp;sessionPID=70dd3b7a-2b76-40ce-98ea-ac10003dccf6&amp;number=20774958&amp;isPrimary=false&amp;absoluteTime=13241245519.395262" aria-hidden="true" src="https://pitt.hosted.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Viewer/Thumb.aspx?eventTargetPID=db184992-2dd3-4257-aa24-ac10003dcc84&amp;sessionPID=70dd3b7a-2b76-40ce-98ea-ac10003dccf6&amp;number=20774958&amp;isPrimary=false&amp;absoluteTime=13241245519.395262">
                                <div class="thumbnail-timestamp" aria-label="Preview image at 0:00">0:00</div>
                                
                            </li>
```

Comment: I can not provide an exact solution as you have not shared HTML DOM or page link. However couple of suggestions like is your page having dynamically loading javascript like once you ove your cursor somewhere then only page text is loading. Also your comment is little off regarding explicit wit in first line. It will not wait for 30 sec before it start looking for elements rather than it will look up to 30 sec for the elements to appear. As it might be possible yours element are located but text has not rendered completely. Please share page link / HTML for more debugging.

Comment: @rahulrai thank you for your reply, I have added the relevant HTML... as you can see there is definitely some scripting involved but why cant/ how can webdriver scrape directly from the page source? (I am after the timestamps)

Comment: Still I am not able to reproduce / understand  your issue completely. But i can see element with thumbnail i inside script tag. So to get text you should use **thumbnail.get_attribute("innerHTML")** rather than thumbnail.text.